# GAE Key part searching

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm new to this :)

```
class P()

class C( .. Key(with custom_ID, parent=P))
```

Can I do a C key get globally -> ie without using the parent P key?

If not, how could I do C key get globally for a `custom_ID`?

`custom_ID` is guaranteed to be unique across C.

Please help me.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No. The minute you put a parent in the key,  a direct get requires the full key.  You would have to do a query based on some property of the entity. ie putting custom id in a property. How will you guarantee custom_ID will be unique.

Comment: OK, thanks. But then the datastores consistency policy might miss a query fetch on an indexed custom_ID. How to get around this? Have a class without parent with custom_ID key?

Comment: Yes if you do query you could miss stuff. However a get with a key is consistent. The whole consistent query discussion is about Query's and to be consistent they need an ancestor. (ie  query only entities in the same entity group.) An entity with no parent, is the root of a new entity group. Which means you can't do strongly consistent queries across entities that don't share a parent.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Hoffman commented, once an entity has a parent, the parent id is part of the entity's key.

This is handy, as you could have 2 objects with the same id, but a different parent. Their keys will be different, as the parent's id will also be part of their key.